# How do I remove a conflict of identical tables (Material Sortable Datatable) on the same page?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

**HI**. Found a table on [codepin](https://codepen.io/azamatms/pen/ZGwOMM).

when I place two "Material Sortable Datatable", one of them does not work, the first one works.

**Decided this way:**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#datatable').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sStripClasses": "",
      "sSearch": "",
      "sSearchPlaceholder": "Enter Keywords Here",
      "sInfo": "_START_ -_END_ of _TOTAL_",
      "sLengthMenu": '<span>Rows per page:</span><select class="browser-default">' +
        '<option value="10">10</option>' +
        '<option value="20">20</option>' +
        '<option value="30">30</option>' +
        '<option value="40">40</option>' +
        '<option value="50">50</option>' +
        '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
        '</select></div>'
    },
    bAutoWidth: false
  });



  $('#datatable2').dataTable({
    "oLanguage": {
      "sStripClasses": "",
      "sSearch": "",
      "sSearchPlaceholder": "Enter Keywords Here",
      "sInfo": "_START_ -_END_ of _TOTAL_",
      "sLengthMenu": '<span>Rows per page:</span><select class="browser-default">' +
        '<option value="10">10</option>' +
        '<option value="20">20</option>' +
        '<option value="30">30</option>' +
        '<option value="40">40</option>' +
        '<option value="50">50</option>' +
        '<option value="-1">All</option>' +
        '</select></div>'
    },
    bAutoWidth: false
  });

});
```

**It works, but when I refresh the page a window appears.**

### [image]

Tried to fix it with a parameter **bdestroy: true,** not help. Help my^^

Comment: That shouldnt happen given those are 2 different elements, are you certain there is not a 3rd call to .dataTable() somewhere in your code? Perhaps something like $('table').datatable();  from another example or something>?

Comment: @Wesley Smith, Yes, indeed! Thank you, good man)